# Can't Export Android Application in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, andengine

I'm experiencing some strange behavior in Eclipse. I'm trying to export my Android application, which is a game that is written using AndEngine, the open source game engine. Not sure if that is relevant.

Anyway, there are no errors in my project or the library dependencies of Android. I have been running the application on my phone with the debug build for ages. Now I want to export a signed application, and it won't work! (It did used to).

I right click my project, click Android Tools > Export Signed Application and *right* when I do that, two errors show up that say,

> No .class files were found in project "AndEngine" so none of the classfile basechecks could be run . Does the project need to be built first?
>
> No .class files were found in project "AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension" so none of the classfile basechecks could be run . Does the project need to be built first?

How the heck do I fix this? I have done a Project > Clean, open and closed Eclipse, open and closed the individual projects. And again - this error is NOT there until I go to export the app! What the heck!

Comment: added the proper and exact warning as answer below :) if you're still interested :) cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I think I figured this out. Not sure of the "real" issue, but my workaround for the time being is to right click my project in the file tree on the left, then click Properties. I selected the "Android Lint Preferences" in the dialog that comes up, and just hit "Ignore All". Now I can build without the error.

While this is a work around, I'm not thrilled about leaving that disabled completely. I'd like to know which Lint preference i can specifically disable. (I, quite frankly, don't even know what lint is)

Answer (score 3):

I solve this problem turning off **Build Automatically** in Eclipse before export.

Answer (score 0):

Are those projects set as libraries?

Open Project -> Properties.
Click Android on the left.
Scroll down and make sure under Libraries that "Is Library" is checked.

Comment: Thanks, but yea they are. As I said in the post, I actually have done this before. That's why I'm so confused. I haven't exported a build in a while, just running debug builds (deploying it to my phone while plugged in) and now when I go to export it doesn't work!!

Comment: Looking at my andengine game I have the entire andengine source in its own folder in my project's root folder.... Its a folder called andengine_src. It might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

probably just add:

```
<issue id="LintError" severity="ignore" />
```

to your **lint.xml** config file.
In **eclipse** probably **just set this one *(LintError)* error to ignore**.